# SQL: SELECT FROM (SELECT, SELECT)

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, hour

I receive data from a counter, and I want to create a report that print how much was incremented per hour.

I made this query, but I couldn't do a SELECT from 0 to 23 Hours

```
 SELECT  [COLUMN_A],
         [COLUMN_B],
         [COLUMN_A] - [COLUMN_B] AS TOTAL


FROM (
    (SELECT MAX([_Counter]) AS COLUMN_A 
     FROM [DADOS].[dbo].Table_Producao] 
     WHERE DatePart(HOUR, _TimeStamp)=9)AS PART_A

    CROSS JOIN(SELECT MAX([_Count]) AS COLUMN_B 
               FROM [DADOS].[dbo].[Table_Producao] 
               WHERE DatePart(HOUR, _TimeStamp)=8)AS PART_B
    )
```

What a I have:

```
_TimeStamp                _Counter
2015-02-03 14:00:00.000     2
2015-02-03 14:59:00.000     15
2015-02-03 15:00:00.000     17
2015-02-03 15:30:00.000     30
2015-02-03 15:59:00.000     42
2015-02-03 16:00:00.000     43
2015-02-03 16:30:00.000     50
2015-02-03 16:59:00.000     59
2015-02-03 17:00:00.000     61
2015-02-03 17:30:00.000     70
2015-02-03 17:50:00.000     82
2015-02-03 18:00:00.000     86
2015-02-03 18:30:00.000     90
2015-02-03 18:59:00.000     99
2015-02-03 19:00:00.000     102
2015-02-03 19:30:00.000     115
2015-02-03 19:59:00.000     124
2015-02-03 20:00:00.000     126
2015-02-03 20:30:00.000     137
2015-02-03 20:59:00.000     145
2015-02-03 21:00:00.000     147
```

What I want:

```
_TimeStamp       _Counter
14h                 17
15h                 27
16h                 17
17h                 23
18h                 17
19h                 25
20h                 21
21h                 2
```

Any ideas? please

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
SELECT Cast(Datepart(hh, [_timestamp]) AS VARCHAR(3))+ 'h',
       Sum(_counter)
FROM   your_result
GROUP  BY Cast(Datepart(hh, [_timestamp]) AS VARCHAR(3))+ 'h',
          Cast(_timestamp AS DATE)
```

Comment: please explain your answer in an effort to help OP understand what your solution code does

Answer (score 0):

I solved my qestion with this query:

```
WITH QUERY1 AS
    (SELECT MAX(_Counter) AS MAX_1,  Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp]) AS _TIMESTAMP1
    FROM Table
    WHERE Cast(DatePart(hh, TimeStamp)AS int) IN (SELECT Cast(Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp]) AS int) 
    FROM   Table
    WHERE TimeStamp>=CAST('<%DataQuery%>'+' 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AND TimeStamp<=CAST('<%DataQuery%>'+' 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)
    )
    GROUP  BY Cast(Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp])AS int)),

    QUERY2 AS
    (SELECT MAX(_Counter) AS MAX_2,  Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp]) AS _TIMESTAMP2
    FROM PLASCAR_DADOS.dbo.Table_Producao 
    WHERE Cast(DatePart(hh, TimeStamp)AS int) IN (SELECT Cast(Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp]) AS int)+1 
    FROM   Table
    WHERE TimeStamp>=CAST('<%DataQuery%>'+' 00:00:00.000' AS DATETIME) AND TimeStamp<=CAST('<%DataQuery%>'+' 23:59:59.999' AS DATETIME)
    )
    GROUP  BY Cast(Datepart(hh, [TimeStamp])AS int))


    SELECT  _TIMESTAMP1, MAX_2-MAX_1 AS TOTAL
    FROM QUERY1 INNER JOIN QUERY2 ON _TIMESTAMP1 =_TIMESTAMP2-1
```